# How to split strings from .txt file into a list, sorted from A-Z without duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, text

**For instance, the .txt file includes 2 lines, separated by commas:**

```
John, George, Tom

Mark, James, Tom,
```

Output should be:

```
[George, James, John, Mark, Tom]
```

Comment: Is this homework? Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Reinderien Edited my question. Something isn't working and I don't know where to sort the list (beginning or the end of the block)

Comment: You haven't made an attempt to split on commas.

Comment: @Reinderien I tried, it didn't work so I removed it.

Comment: How is this sorted A-Z? Certainly doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: Just ignore the order, the output doesn't matter, I'm trying to understand the structure of any solution so I can learn from it.

Comment: If the output order doesn't matter, show expected output anyway, and edit your question title.

Comment: @Reinderien I fixed the output, hope it's more readable.

Comment: The order is still incorrect. `Mark` is before `Tom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I came up with a very simple solution if anyone will need:**

```
lines = x.read().split()
lines.sort()
new_list = []
[new_list.append(word) for word in lines if word not in new_list]
return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file opening is fine, although the `'r'` is redundant since that's the default. You claim it's not, but it is. [Read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

You have not described what `task` is so I have no idea what's going on there. I will assume that it is correct.

Rather than populating a list and doing a membership test on every iteration - which is O(n^2) in time - can you think of a different data structure that guarantees uniqueness? Google will be your friend here. Once you discover this data structure, you will not have to perform membership checks at all. You seem to be struggling with this concept; the answer is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set).

The input data format is not rigorously defined. Separators may be commas or commas with trailing spaces, and may appear (or not) at the end of the line. Consider making an appropriate regular expression and using its splitting feature to split individual lines, though normal splitting and stripping may be easier to start.

In the following example code, I've:

- ignored `task` since you've said that that's fine;
- separated actual parsing of file content from parsing of in-memory content to demonstrate the function without a file;
- used a set comprehension to store unique results of all split lines; and
- used a generator to `sorted` that drops empty strings.

```
from io import StringIO
from typing import TextIO, List


def parse(f: TextIO) -> List[str]:
    words = {
        word.strip()
        for line in f
        for word in line.split(',')
    }
    return sorted(
        word for word in words if word != ''
    )


def parse_file(filename: str) -> List[str]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        return parse(f)


def test():
    f = StringIO('John, George , Tom\nMark, James, Tom, ')
    words = parse(f)
    assert words == [
        'George', 'James', 'John', 'Mark', 'Tom',
    ]

    f = StringIO(' Han Solo, Boba Fet \n')
    words = parse(f)
    assert words == [
        'Boba Fet', 'Han Solo',
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: 'r' isn't redundant, because "path" is the user's input.
You can also ignore "task", it's part of the interaction with the user which I didn't remove.
Do you refer to a dictionary instead of a list?
And Google is my friend, but I'm asking here because I couldn't fine any direction towards solution.

Comment: Dictionaries do guarantee uniqueness by key, but have a key-value representation you don't need. What other data structure guarantees uniqueness?

Comment: If you mean tuple, I know it's going to keep everything in order, but it's not what I'm looking for. So the solution must include a list.

Comment: Perhaps you should read some introductory material like https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Collections.html

Comment: I honestly don't understand what does this link have to do with my question.

Comment: I've posed a fundamental data structure question that you need to understand to complete your homework. If you can't answer it, you need to learn about data structures, and that link explains them.

Comment: But my main problem is working with the text file, not with the data structure, which *must* be a list because this is the exercise. Sorting the list from A-Z is my last problem. My main question is how do I split words in a text file while ignoring '\n' so I can create a list of these words?

Comment: I would be happy to help, and in fact my recommendation using `re.split` will use intermediate lists (as a consequence of how the system library is implemented, not as a requisite feature of the solution), but I won't write the solution out for you unless you help yourself out, here. The uniqueness constraint has an elegant solution for which you need to understand data structures.

Comment: After reading the material you referred to, I still can't finish the code using a list.

Comment: Edited. I hope that this offers a learning opportunity. Please do ask if anything in my offered code is not clear to you.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. However, the code looks very complicated to me and is 3 levels higher than my knowledge. Since it's just an exercise, I think that the way to solve my problem suppose to be easier and shorter, and without importing anything. I guess that I only need to "play" with split + replace, though I still don't know how.

Comment: It won't get much shorter than this (without sacrificing legibility). If the constructs here are foreign to you, it's time to learn :)

Comment: Seems like I was right and the solution was very simple and short (edited my post). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should move that block of code to a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create the list and store each item as a string.

```
def test(path):
    filename = path
    with open(filename) as f:
        f = f.read()
        f_list = f.split('\n')
        for i in f_list:
            if i == '':
                f_list.remove(i)
        res1 = []
        for i in f_list:
            res1.append(i.split(', '))
        res2 = []
        for i in res1:
            res2 += i
        res3 = [i.strip(',') for i in res2]
        for i in res3:
            if res3.count(i) != 1:
                res3.remove(i)
        res3.sort()
        return res3

print(test('location/of/file.txt'))
```

Output:

```
['George', 'James', 'John', 'Mark', 'Tom']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as fl:
    list_ = set()

    for line in fl.readlines():
        line = line.strip("\n")
        line = line.split(",")

        [list_.add(_) for _ in line if _ != '']

print(list_)
```

Comment: This is... not great? The empty-hack for trailing commas should be dealt with at the `split` level and not after; it ignores `task`; and you shouldn't use a list comprehension if you're only going to throw it away. Also, variables should only be `_` if they're unused.

Comment: It's also actually just wrong; it doesn't sort.

Comment: Also spaces are not dealt with properly given your use of `split`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you missed a comma after Jim in the first line.

You can avoid the use of a loop by using split property :

```
content=file.read()
my_list=content.split(",")
```

to delete the occurence in your list you can transform it to set :

```
my_list=list(set(my_list))
```

then you can sort it using **sorted**

so the finale code :

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file : 

    content=file.read()
    my_list=content.replace("\n","").replace(" ", "").split(",")

    result=sorted(list(set(my_list)))
```

> you can add a key to your sort function

Comment: This will not work. It doesn't handle new lines or spaces after commas. Finally, your indentation is wrong in your example so will fail interpretation.

Comment: it handles new lines after commas, you can see in the finale code the function replace which replace all new lines with an empty string, and spaces are handled with the split function

Comment: Perhaps you should read the [documentation for split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). If a string is passed, it does not split on whitespace.

Comment: I encourage you to try actually executing this code. As it stands, it will concatenate the last word of every line with the first word of the subsequent line, which is incorrect.